# *Missing Push Notification Entitlement* for Local Notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, app-store, apple-push-notifications, app-store-connect

It is not clear to me whether we need to request push notification permissions in the provisioning profile, if we are only sending local notifications. I received the warning email when doing a test upload to ITunes and do not want to waste time when we submit.

I have calls for IOS8+

```
static const UIUserNotificationType USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPES_REQUIRED = UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge;

UIUserNotificationSettings* requestedSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPES_REQUIRED categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:requestedSettings];
```

and

```
[application scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

But no push notification. Do I need to include push in the IOS-APP ID Settings

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Local notifications do not need any changes to the entitlements.

Remote push notifications require you to enable Push Notifications in the entitlements and you will also need a developer account.